# jboss with oracle db - connection issue

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss

I'm struggling for two hours to deploy an application on Jboss server which connects to my Oracle DB.

The dbname-ds.xml has:

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>dbnameDatasource</jndi-name>
        <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.168.105:1521:XE</connection-url>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <user-name>system</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

The credentials are ok because I've tested them using DataBase home page tool from Oracle.

The error I receive in jboss is:

```
  00:14:28,383 INFO  [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider:
 org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
00:14:28,389 INFO  [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] Using provided datasou
rce
00:14:49,476 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to ge
t a new connection: null
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested
 throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not
establish the connection)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.g
etLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:225)
```

//etc

and caused by:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not es
tablish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
```

Do you have any idea where to look?

I've also modified the default localhost to be my ip from ds file:

> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.168.105)(PORT = 1521))

so the host and port is correct.

What else can be the cause...?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: This is definitely a problem with your JDBC URL, and nothing to do with JBoss.  See if you can get a connection with SQL Developer (or similar tool), using that URL.

Comment: Does simple JDBC (w/o hosting in JBoss environment) work?

Comment: I have used Sql Dev and on the above ip it does not work but only on localhost, which is strange...So I've replaced the ip from my ds with localhost and now all seems good...