# How to connect to an Oracle DB from another system

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection

I have installed Oracle 11g on my system and i am able to connect to database using simple java program.

```
ORACLE_USER = "user1"
ORACLE_PASSWORD = "user1"
ORACLE_HOST = "localhost"
ORACLE_SID = "ORCL"
ORACLE_PORT = "1521 "  

String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=" + ORACLE_HOST
                    + ")(protocol=tcp)(port=" + ORACLE_PORT + "))(connect_data=(sid=" + ORACLE_SID + ")))";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, ORACLE_USER,ORACLE_PASSWORD);
```

Now, I want to connect my team mates system's database(LAN network). I am able to ping that system.
The Only change i did in above code is

```
ORACLE_HOST = "kdsystem" //machine name
```

but same code fails and showing following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the
 connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:
    414)
......
....
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: do you check that the listener of the oracle server is started ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..yup both system's listener are started.

Comment: This sounds like as if real name of that server is not `kdsystem` but something else. What happens when you run `ping kdsystem` from the commandline? Btw: you don't need such a complicate URL `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl` is enough.

Comment: you can also try tnsping ORCL from your station to check if your station resolv it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: when i ping kdsystem or with ip address
Reply from ***.**.**.***: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.**.**.***: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.**.**.***: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.**.**.***: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for ***.**.**.***:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: on the oracle server, can you show us the result of the command  lsnrctl status
which should display something like (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=kdsystem)(port=1521)) ?

Comment: Sounds like there is some firewall running on the machine named *kdsystem*

Comment: @FoxMaSk: The output is 
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Comment: its looks like the server is not available for other ip than loopback , does a netstat -an|grep 1521 display other ip than 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

On your team mate machine you can check with netstat or other tool if it is listening on ORACLE_PORT and on ORACLE_HOST (IP adress visible to your machine, or 0.0.0.0). You can check it on Linux/unix machine with:

```
netstat -an | grep 1521
```

or on Windows machine where `grep` is not available:

```
netstat -an | findstr 1521
```

Show us results of such command.

If Oracle is listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) then other machines cannot connect with it. You will have to configure Oracle server to address available to others.

If Oracle is listening on address available to other machines, then check if you can connect to that machine using telnet. If it cannot connect with Oracle then probably there is firewall or similar blockade between those two machines.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I tried with telnet command and got following output.
C:\>telnet kdsystem
Connecting To kdsystem;...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23
: Connect failed

Comment: seems there is some blocker,how to unblock that.?

Comment: No, with telnet you must also use port on which Oracle is listening: `telnet kdsystem 1521`

Comment: Probably your team mate machine has firewall enabled. Try to disable it (only for test purposes) and if you can connect from your machine then enable it and disable only Oracle port. This page will be helpful: http://www.home-network-help.com/windows-firewall.html

Comment: you should have a look at this [which looks exactly like your behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148367/jboss-with-oracle-db-connection-issue?rq=1)

the ip is the issue (which seems to be the loopback) like I supposed in my last comment.

Comment: OK, added more info about checking for is Oracle is listening on address available to others.